# Word lists for constructed languages

Tags: language, worldbuilding-process, worldbuilding-resources, conlang

When building a language for your world, words are "surprisingly" important. All natural language have words of some kind and only **extremely** experimental constructed languages lack them.

Word choice and categories are often difficult to create from scratch, so surely there must be a simpler way to create words?

Are there any lists that include words for lexicon creation?

---

To Cort’s notes, I am looking for a list containing a large amount of words, varying across all kinds of words, hence why the [Swadesh list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swadesh_list) is insufficent

Comment: Are you asking for a vocabulary list of "these are the N most common words that your new language will want to define"?

Comment: @SRM that would be an acceptable answer, links to such a list would also be good.

Comment: something like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swadesh_list ?

Comment: @MolbOrg that list is too simple for my liking, so no

Comment: did't meant exactly this, kinda like it, language core like. Actually anything like learn language in 14 days, phrasebook etc. In that direction there are vocabularies of different sizes, like different minimals to know. In print format it is more obvious, and was pretty common. They included words based on frequencies. Online corpus of language saw few resources - you should ask more linguistic oriented peoples(translators and such), google had some sort of corpus online with time graph how often and when it was used, cant remember link now, and doubt it could be used in form of database.

Comment: Can you expand on your issues with MolbOrg's recommendation of the Swadesh list?  It seems like a very good match for what you have written the question to be.  I think if you make it too complicated of a list, you're going to start getting into cultural questions which are not universal

Comment: @CortAmmon okay

Comment: Any particular kind of language, i.e. sounds, alphabet?  Seems like you are looking for word roots as in natural language processing.  Also out of curiosity, what to do you mean by "experimental" language without words - do you mean like a grammar in a formal language?

Comment: See also this question and its answers: https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/459/whats-a-good-starting-place-to-work-on-vocab

Comment: I've started putting together a list of [base words for Tune](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GxKYr8wTVQyGuotdQTrG1DJh92KBSqvxF-zC-3kISBs/edit?usp=sharing) (3000+ words). I have put in a lot of effort to get only "base" words into this list, but it's still missing a lot. Some words are very close to other words ("say, talk, speak, tell"), so you could potentially leave those out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are lists of [lemmatized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787110/what-is-the-true-difference-between-lemmatization-vs-stemming#1787121) word roots.  Just pick a language that comes closest to suiting your needs.

<s>`http://www.lexiconista.com/datasets/lemmatization/`</s>

Edit:

The above link is dead.  The relevant lists are now available on Github:

https://github.com/michmech/lemmatization-lists/

Comment: interesting set of Slavic languages))

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: @Craeft fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Zompist.com's Conlanger's Lexipedia has the Fantasy Frequency Wordlist, which is a list of 1500 very common words, and can be found here (click the link to the text file near the top:
http://www.zompist.com/resources/lex.html

There is also a set of wordlists at the back of the Language Construction Kit.
As for assigning words to these, there is also a vocabulary generator, available here:
http://www.zompist.com/gen.html

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think he's actually published the List as of yet (it seems to be a long term work in progress), but you might consider checking out the [Landau Core Vocabulary](https://cbbforum.com/viewtopic.php?p=1505#p1505). I think this will end up beating the Swadesh List by at least an order of magnitude.