# Basic/core vocabulary for a general-use fantasy language?

Tags: worldbuilding-resources, conlang

So, when it comes to words, people cut corners. With various rules, they combined pre-existing words into new ones. While it's true the results were often horrifying (giraffe/zsiráf = foltos nyakorrján; steam locomotive/gőzmozdony = gőzpöffögészeti tovalöködönc). However, some of them stuck.

Every language starts out with a basic vocabulary that contains essential words like states of being (alive, dead, inanimate, political). Now, what I need is a list of these essential words. From there, I should be able to create new words with classical tactics.

**However, I'm struggling to find a list of basic words, do you know where I can find one?**

The language is supposed to have many words, as it's used to name places and people, worldbuilding-wise.

Comment: Names can be words, but a lot of names (in languages I am familiar with) are not words in that language.

Comment: What you may need is a lexicon of morphemes. Here's an [English one](http://www.fldoe.org/core/fileparse.php/16294/urlt/morphemeML.pdf) as an example. If you're unable for some reason to get a good answer here, try [conlang.se], our sister site. "Political" is made from "people" originally from "city"  and "about", it's not a basic word but a built-up one.

Comment: The is no such thing as a "universal" core vocabulary. For practical purposes of linguistic comparison, the most usual list is the 100-word [Swadesh list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swadesh_list). (The core vocabulary of most languages has 300 to 400 words.) (Specifically for English, the you can start with the [General Service List](http://jbauman.com/aboutgsl.html).)

Comment: @Willk: Names are most usually meaningful -- Archi-medes "Great Planner", Aristo-teles "Noble Goal", Alex-ander "Defender of Men", Cassi-opeia "Shining Face", Andro-meda "Minder of Men", Bere-nice "Bringer of Victory", Cleo-patra "Glory of Her Father" etc. It is our [WEIRD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychology#WEIRD_bias) civilization which is weird, in that for some strange reason we prefer to use foreign (mostly Hebrew and Greek) names -- and we dont' even have the excuse of having been conquered by the Hebrews!

Comment: @AlexP Speak for your culture. Slavic languages retain large amount of meaningful names. I'm sure you will find Vladimir "Ruler of the world/peace" Putin's name appropriate to his ambitions, to give a VERY famous example.

Comment: @Miech: Yes, I know. (And we Romanians happily use Slavic names, such as Bogdan, Miroslav, Vladislav, Vladimir and so on, which are of course meaningless in our language.)

Comment: @AlexP You should be using Roman names like August(us) "esteemed, majestic", Faust(us) "lucky", Luke/Lucas/Lucius "bright" or Roman "roman" instead of Bogdan "god given", Miroslav "praising peace"/"famous peacemaker", Vladislav "famous, esteemed" or Vladimir "ruler of the world"/"ruler of the peace" then.

Comment: I won't start the VTC ball rolling because I think language questions have a place here - but traditionally questions about how to construct languages have been rapidly closed and discussions on Meta have supported those closures because they're so completely opinion based. Of the four words you suggest as "essential," the only one that might be considered so is "dead." The others are actually very complex (the first recorded use of "inanimate" was 1479, hardly a core word). Frankly, the only "core word" I can think of is "mine!"

Comment: And it doesn't help that SE has an entire stack ([conlang.se]) devoted to the construction of language where this answer may already exist.

Comment: @AlexP that was a fabulous reference (to the GSL), but even it has limits. It combined words that have no purpose but to express grammar (e.g., articles) and doesn't include words that are far more frequently used than almost everything on that list - but wouldn't be included out of [good taste](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjzhs7gWueQ).

Comment: i dont quite get your question since language is not my vorte, but this seems more western centric or latin stuff. also sound like you want some universal type of dictionary book? or am i wrong?

Comment: @Miech: Oh, we are. Bogdan, for example, has competition from the native Tudor and the westernized Teodor. (History is complicated, and all nations are the end result of their history.)

Comment: Final comment on this naive question: *some* languages are happy to compound words; examples include Greek and German and Mandarin Chinese. Other languages, such as Latin and the Romance languages in general are very reluctant to use composition and very much prefer derivation with prefixes and suffixes. European languages in general have found a source of words in the classical languages, and use that source on a large scale for their needs; for example, locomotive (Latin), political (Greek) or television (Greco-Latin hybrid). And *all* languages borrow words ready made from foreigners.

Comment: Related question: https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/459/whats-a-good-starting-place-to-work-on-vocab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word lists for constructed languages](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/54843/word-lists-for-constructed-languages)

Answer (score 1):

There is a recently invented language named Toki Pona that [claims to be a full language](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2015/07/toki-pona-smallest-language/398363/) that has about 123 words.

For real spoken languages it seems that Taki Taki only has 340 words.

> Language with the fewest words: Taki Taki (also called Sranan), 340 words. Taki Taki is an English-based Creole spoken by 120,000 in the South American country of Suriname.

([Source](https://www.vistawide.com/languages/language_statistics.htm))

[This website](https://universeofmemory.com/how-many-words-you-should-know/) makes some interesting claims about the number of words to be able to understand and comprehend a language. I am a little skeptical, but it seems the person who did the website looked at some academic sources.

It seems there are a variety of vocabulary lists around are either grouped by the frequency of use, or for teaching purposes. I am not sure if that is useful for your purposes.

There is a guy, [David J. Peterson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_J._Peterson), who invents languages used in a variety of tv shows and movies, who wrote

> The Art of Language Invention: From Horse-Lords to Dark Elves, the Words Behind World-Building

I haven't read it, but the premise seems to be interesting.

Comment: Toki Pona is not a natural or general-use language.